# Consuming webapi with two parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Hello I am learning WebApi and got this problem. Hours of search didn't yield any solution.

I am trying to call an api passing two parameters just for testing purposes. The one on which I am getting 404 error is `GetBalance(param1, param2)`. I have another function exposed by the Api called `GetOffice(param1)` with one parameter which returns 200. The 404 I am getting is for the two parameter function.

```
public void GetBalance(string accountNumber,int officeId)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json");
            client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");
            client.Headers.Add("API_KEY","1234CHECK");
            var result = client.DownloadString("http://localhost/api/Accounts/GetBalance/" + accountNumber  + officeId ); //URI 
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + result);

        }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsumeApiSync objSync = new ConsumeApiSync();
        objSync.GetBalance("01-13-00000595", 1);
    }
```

Route

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("OfficeApi", "api/{controller}/{action}/{accountNumber}/{officeId}");
```

I get 404 not found error. What must be wrong? Help Appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Missing `/` between `accountNumber` and `officeId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your request URI is not correct.

```
var uri = string.Concat("http://localhost/api/Accounts/GetBalance/", accountNumber, "/", officeId);
```

Try the following code.

```
public void GetBalance(string accountNumber,int officeId)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json");
        client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");
        client.Headers.Add("API_KEY","1234CHECK");
        var uri = string.Concat("http://localhost/api/Accounts/GetBalance/", accountNumber, "/", officeId);
        var result = client.DownloadString(uri); //URI 
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + result);

    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConsumeApiSync objSync = new ConsumeApiSync();
    objSync.GetBalance("01-13-00000595", 1);
}
```

Comment: Prob was with the URI.Worked now.Thank you sir.

Answer (score 2):

use a view model on your Web Api controller that contains both properties. So instead of:

```
public HttpresponseMessage  GetBalance(string accountNumber,int officeId)
{
    ...
}
```

use:

```
public HttpresponseMessage Post(ViewModelName model)
{
    ...
}
```

> ```
>    var uri = string.Concat("http://localhost/api/Accounts/GetBalance",model);
> ```

Comment: Thank you sir.Can you tell me the pros of using viewmodel?